# ButtonView with different background

Tags: android, android-button, rounded-corners

I have designed a rounded corners button.

**button_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>

</shape>
```

**In layout:**

```
<Button
   android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
.../>
```

on every click the color of the should button changes :

**In activity, inside onClickListener():**

```
btn1.setBackgroundColor(getAnswerColor(choiceArray[0]));
```

but if I do this, I am not getting the rounder corners.

How to get rounder corners? Please suggest.

Comment: Post code for button_selector.xml

Comment: Please check the above code.

Comment: please check answer and give response...

Comment: @megha if you have to make button with rounder corners you can make with toolsite which i have mention in my answer.Make button with that site ,copy the code and apply to your project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);

GradientDrawable drawableGradient = (GradientDrawable) btn1.getBackground();
drawableGradient .setColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your button from this toolsite ==> [Android Button Maker](http://angrytools.com/android/button/)

You can make any kind of button with this tool with Code.

Here i edit this Answer as your requirement.

so,make two different button for with different background color and use selector for changing background onClick.For that use this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/click_button" android:state_pressed="true" />
<!-- When not selected, use white-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/not_click_button" android:state_pressed="false" />

</selector>
```

Comment: any customized style that is created, is set as background to ButtonView. And while changing the background color of ButtonView dynamically, I have to set the backgroundColor, which in return is cancelling the effect of style.

Comment: i have edit my answer for your requirement,follow this may you get your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**try this way**

**i checked with below xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item >
<shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="13dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
     <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#8dbab3" android:endColor="#58857e" />            
 </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

**on button click add this code**

```
  StateListDrawable drawable = (StateListDrawable) v.getBackground();
  drawable.setColorFilter(Color.RED,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
  button1.setBackground(drawable);
```